# How to attach list of constants to a run in tensorboard?

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard

I'm logging my pytorch DNN experiments with tensorboard, it would be really nice if there was some way to programmatically attach a list of constants (eg. hyperparams) to each run (and maybe even notes?) so that I can see easily see what effect different constants have had. Is this possible?

Edit: `add_text` kind of does this but it's still a step-oriented thing rather than a run-oriented thing. so browsing 20 hyperparameters over a dozen experiments would involve a lot of scrolling:
[image]

I'd really like to be able to see them all at a glance, maybe in the hover dialog whilst inspecting the curves - maybe this isn't possible and I should be making a feature-request rather than an SO question?
[image]

Comment: How about [add_text](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html#torch.utils.tensorboard.writer.SummaryWriter.add_text)?

Comment: ok, I guess this isn't possible. I've submitted a feature request
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/4674